# problem with the nested gridview asp.net/C#

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview1 which is the parent gridview and I want to insert another gridview2 which is child gridview inside every row of parent gridview

This is the code in the .aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gridView2" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the code that I have added inside the RowDataBound Event and i'm just binding the gridview2 with the arraylist which is filtered data depending upon the contents of each row's invoice number

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gridviewrow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                gridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                String x = gridviewrow.Cells[1].Text;
                softwareTitlesList = SoftwareListRetrieve();
                ArrayList titles = new ArrayList();
                foreach (SoftwareTitles softwareTitle in softwareTitlesList)
                {
                    if (softwareTitle.InvoiceNumber.Contains(x))
                        titles.Add(softwareTitle.SoftwareTitle);
                }
                gridView2.DataSource = titles;
                gridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

But nothing seems to be happening.

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RowDataBound event fire when Rows bind the data. you have to do like...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            gridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            String x = dr["yourColumnName"].ToString();
            softwareTitlesList = SoftwareListRetrieve();
            ArrayList titles = new ArrayList();
            foreach (SoftwareTitles softwareTitle in softwareTitlesList)
            {
                if (softwareTitle.InvoiceNumber.Contains(x))
                    titles.Add(softwareTitle.SoftwareTitle);
            }
            GridView gridView2 = (GridView)e.Row.Findcontrol("gridView2");//add this
            gridView2.DataSource = titles;
            gridView2.DataBind();

    }
}
```

**Edit for comments:**

```
GridView gridView2 = (GridView)e.Row.Findcontrol("gridView2");// add this line
```

Comment: I have a new problem now it is giving me error "The name 'gridView2' does not exist in the current context" Is there any thing else i need to add to be able to access inside the .aspx.cs file

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) Even this method is not getting called !! What is the problem ?

Comment: you have to add event in your Gridview <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

Comment: Thanks Muhammad !! I owe you. Thank you for immediate responses. It worked. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are doing this inside the `RowDataBound` Event. This is going to be fired for every row in `GridView1` that is bound to the datasource. You are essentially resetting the DataSource for `GridView2` every time. Try using the `DataBound` Event of the gridview instead.

Comment: can u put your idea into coding. It would be more clear for me. Please !! Thanks in anticipation !

Comment: But if you put it inside a DataBound, then how are you going to iterate through each row updating GridView2 and making it refresh for each row? I tried this and it made all the GridView2 data look the same as the first row's GridView2.